# Codeigniter 2.1 : push more new value in session array every time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I my CI application I hit an ajax button, call controller action and want to push new value in already existing session array on every hit. I google but file.

Following are the sources which I tried.

[add value into userdata array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467101/add-value-into-userdata-array)

[Session Array Update in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313975/session-array-update-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I did it :

1- first load old array
2- push new value to array
3- set session

```
$old_que_ans_session =  $this->session->userdata('que_ans_session');
array_push($old_que_ans_session, $qIds[$_POST['my_que_no']]);
$this->session->set_userdata('que_ans_session', $old_que_ans_session);
```

Comment: Seriously, we can't push a new value straight ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('user');  

$data['telno'] = "01234 567 890";  

$this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
```

Hope it may help full.

Thanks